# A Short Simple Riley

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, acrostic

Okay, okay; I've been enjoying writing my stories lately, but have hit a road block with my newest one. Thus, I created another easy Riley for you guys to solve!

> Take the prefix and circle the answer; a short and angled climb.
>
> Examine the infix and you will see; one out of two in a line.
>
> Study the suffix using your eyes; a letter both you and I know.
>
> Throw twenty-six, at the end of the mix; the answer is finally shown.

- What is the answer?
- How does it relate to each line?
- How does it relate to the puzzle as a whole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you a

> Quiz

Take the prefix and circle the answer; a short and angled climb.

> Q is like a circle with a tail.

Examine the infix and you will see; one out of two in a line.

> This is "u"

Study the suffix using your eyes; a letter both you and I know.

> This is "i" or eye

Throw twenty-six, at the end of the mix; the answer is finally shown.

> The 26th letter of the alphabet is "z"

Also

> The acrostic is "TEST"

Comment: You found this too quickly!

Comment: @PerpetualJ after looking at this awesome answer, that was a really clever riddle! I did not even notice the Rot13(npebfgvpf), which is unlike me, hahah! DVL2, so I favourited $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D